# HTML categories does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a navigation menu, which is built depending on the data, which I have as a dictionary array.
And I have issues, after GET, PARSE and SORT data from array. I want to build the HTML from a jQuery loop. In the console I saw, that all the HTML elements appear:

[image]

However, I didn't see them appear on my page.

My code:

```js
var mokData = [
{ mainCategory: "Technical", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-1-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Technical", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-1-2', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Technical", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-1-3', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-4-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-3-2', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-11-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-12-11', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-12-11', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-12-13', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-12-17', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-2-11', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-1-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-122-121', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Other", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Other", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Other", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-1-11', name: 'Brakedown of line', clicked: 0 }
];

var parseCategorys = [...mokData.reduce((c, { mainCategory, subCategory }) => {
if (!c.has(mainCategory)) c.set(mainCategory, { mainCategory, subCategory: [] });
c.get(mainCategory).subCategory.push(subCategory);
return c;
}, new Map()).values()];


$(document).ready(function () {
$('.category_list .category_item[category="all"]').addClass('ct_item-active');

$('.category_item').click(function () {
    var catProduct = $(this).attr('category');
    console.log(catProduct);
    
    
    $.each(parseCategorys, function (i, data) {
        if (catProduct === data.mainCategory) {
            var uniqueNames = [];
            $.each(data.subCategory, function (i, el) {
                if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
            });

            $.each(uniqueNames, function (i, data) {
                console.log(data);
                var subCategoryBuild = '<div class="product-item" category="' + data + '"><div class="categoryLink"><a href="#' + data + '">' + data +'</a></div></div>';
                console.log(subCategoryBuild);
                $('.products-list').append(subCategoryBuild);
            });

           
        }

    });

    
    $('.category_item').removeClass('ct_item-active');
    $(this).addClass('ct_item-active');

    $('.product-item').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
    function hideProduct() {
        $('.product-item').hide();
    } setTimeout(hideProduct, 400);

    function showProduct() {
        $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').show();
        $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
    } setTimeout(showProduct, 400);
});
});

function creatingNavigationList() {
$.each(parseCategorys, function (i, data) {
    var categoryBuild = '<a href="#" class="category_item" category="' + data.mainCategory + '">' + data.mainCategory + '</a>';
    $('.cteatinMainCategory').append(categoryBuild);
});
}

creatingNavigationList()
```

```css
.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wrap > h1 {
    color: #494B4D;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.wrap > h1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C7C7C7;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.store-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.category_list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30%;
}

.category_list .category_item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #E84C3D;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.category_list .ct_item-active {
    background: #2D3E50;
}

.products-list {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.products-list .product-item {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.products-list .product-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.products-list .product-item a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #2D3E50;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="wrap">
            <div class="store-wrapper">
                <div class="category_list">
                    <div class="cteatinMainCategory"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="container2">
                    <div class="section2">
                        <div class="scrollable-content content">
                            <section class="products-list">
                                <div id="creatingSubcat"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**As you can see, on console I have HTML elements, but they don't appear on the page.**

It's not working from the JS file, but if I manually put the code below to the page it will work:

```
<div class="product-item" category="Material"><div class="categoryLink"><a href="#Material">Material</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is really a lot of errors in your javascript. Inside your onclick function on `category_item`.

Your functions `hideProduct` and `showProduct` are both called on click, resulting the subcategories be shown then immediately after hidden.
Also, you set scale of all `.product-item` to 0 so the width of the div is 0 so they can't be displayed.

On a side note: if you use `show()` and `hide()` functions, you shouldn't add a scale change to hide or show items. Also, you should consider populate your HTML once and not on click if this is possible because the way you do it now add more and more node inside your HTML infinitely.

```js
var mokData = [
{ mainCategory: "Technical", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-1-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Technical", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-1-2', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Technical", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-1-3', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-4-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-3-2', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-11-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0  },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-12-11', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-12-11', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Organizational", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-12-13', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-12-17', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-2-11', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-1-1', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-122-121', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Equipment", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Operator", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Other", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Other", subCategory: "Material", id: 'UPDT-122-111', name: 'Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine Brakedown of machine', clicked: 0 },
{ mainCategory: "Other", subCategory: "Tool", id: 'UPDT-1-11', name: 'Brakedown of line', clicked: 0 }
];

var parseCategorys = [...mokData.reduce((c, { mainCategory, subCategory }) => {
if (!c.has(mainCategory)) c.set(mainCategory, { mainCategory, subCategory: [] });
c.get(mainCategory).subCategory.push(subCategory);
return c;
}, new Map()).values()];


$(document).ready(function () {
$('.category_list .category_item[category="all"]').addClass('ct_item-active');

$('.category_item').click(function () {
    var catProduct = $(this).attr('category');
    //console.log(catProduct);
    
    
    $.each(parseCategorys, function (i, data) {
        if (catProduct === data.mainCategory) {
            var uniqueNames = [];
            $.each(data.subCategory, function (i, el) {
                if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
            });

            $.each(uniqueNames, function (i, data) {
                //console.log(data);
                var subCategoryBuild = '<div class="product-item" category="' + data + '"><div class="categoryLink"><a href="#' + data + '">' + data +'</a></div></div>';
                //console.log(subCategoryBuild);
                $('.products-list').append(subCategoryBuild);
            });

           
        }

    });

    
    $('.category_item').removeClass('ct_item-active');
    $(this).addClass('ct_item-active');

    //$('.product-item').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
    function hideProduct() {
        //console.log("hide");
        $('.product-item').hide();
    };
    //setTimeout(hideProduct, 400);

    function showProduct() {
        //console.log("show");
        $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').show();
        $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
    };
    setTimeout(showProduct, 400);
});
});

function creatingNavigationList() {
$.each(parseCategorys, function (i, data) {
    var categoryBuild = '<a href="#" class="category_item" category="' + data.mainCategory + '">' + data.mainCategory + '</a>';
    $('.cteatinMainCategory').append(categoryBuild);
});
}

creatingNavigationList()
```

```css
.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wrap > h1 {
    color: #494B4D;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.wrap > h1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C7C7C7;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.store-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.category_list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30%;
}

.category_list .category_item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #E84C3D;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.category_list .ct_item-active {
    background: #2D3E50;
}

.products-list {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.products-list .product-item {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.products-list .product-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.products-list .product-item a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #2D3E50;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="wrap">
            <div class="store-wrapper">
                <div class="category_list">
                    <div class="cteatinMainCategory"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="container2">
                    <div class="section2">
                        <div class="scrollable-content content">
                            <section class="products-list">
                                <div id="creatingSubcat"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```